# Create a Button to open link generated from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below is js code on what i am trying to make a button in html. It used getelementbyid . I am learning js. and i don't know what else i can do it fix this. By this method. i want to make a wordpress plugin to place a button on sidebar to open html pages of that current page.

```
const DEFAULT_URL = "https://www.hashhackers.com/use-google-amp-cdn-links-reduce-hosting-resources/amp";
const AMP_CACHE_PREFIX = "https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/";

class AmpUrlConverter {

  constructor(root, ampUrlFactory) {
    this.inputView = root.getElementById('input');
    this.resultView = root.getElementById('result');
    this.ampUrlFactory = ampUrlFactory;
    root.getElementById('execute')
      .addEventListener("click", this.onClick.bind(this));
  }

  setInput(urlString) {
    this.inputView.value = urlString;
    this.convert(urlString);
  }

  convert(urlString) {
    urlString = urlString.trim();
    if (!urlString) {
      this.showError('Empty input');
      return;
    }
    if (!/^http[s]?\:\/\//i.test(urlString)) {
      urlString = 'http://' + urlString;
      this.inputView.value = urlString;
    }
    try {
      const ampUrl = this.ampUrlFactory.createAmpUrl(urlString);
      const proxyUrl = ampUrl.getProxyUrl();
      this.showResult('<a href="' + proxyUrl + '" target="_blank">' + proxyUrl + '</a>');
    }catch(e) {
      this.showError('Invalid URL');
    }
  }

  showError(message) {
    this.resultView.className = 'error';
    this.resultView.innerHTML = message;
  }

  showResult(result) {
    this.resultView.className = '';
    this.resultView.innerHTML = result;
  }

  onClick() {
    this.convert(this.inputView.value);
  }

}

function getParameterByName(name, defaultValue) {
  const url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  const regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) { return defaultValue; }
  if (!results[2]) { return defaultValue; }
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

const proxyUrlPrefix = 'https://cdn.ampproject.org';
const javascriptVersion = '5';
const useCurlsEncoding = true;
const ampUrlFactory = 
  new AmpUrlFactory(proxyUrlPrefix, javascriptVersion, useCurlsEncoding);

const converter = new AmpUrlConverter(document, ampUrlFactory);
const initialUrl = window.location.href + "/amp/";

converter.setInput(initialUrl);
```

currently i am printing it using these elements, and its a link

```
<section class="result-container">
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</section>
```

i want to change it into a button where on click it should open the link but full url shouldn't be shown.

i tried this

```
<input type="button" name="Click" onclick="window.location = getElementById('result')" value="Click Here">
```

Comment: Hi, Stackoverflow is not a coding service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't post pictures on code. Post the code in the question, so we can help

Comment: @AlenGenzić Updated. Check

Comment: @Olearn added the code. please help now.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the location.href on onclick event

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Go to Google" />
```

or

write a function and call it inside onclick

```
<input type="button" onclick="goToLink()" value="Go to Google" />
```

-- function --

```
function goToLink(){
window.location.href= "http://www.google.lk";
}
```

Comment: This is for basic. The url is dynamic. and js is used to modify it into another link. check code. post updated.